# Unique periodic work stop executing after a while

Tags: android, android-workmanager, android-jobscheduler

I've implemented a Unique Periodic Work with WorkManager API in my app. The work has to check every 30min an online resource and show a notification if there are some unread notifications. Yes, I need a periodic work because the resource is a IMAP server, and thus I cannot use FCM notifications.
However the job is correctly scheduled as I can see with `dumpsys jobscheduler`, but after a while the job sto executing. When I run `dumpsys jobscheduler` I read something like this:

```
JOB #u0a360/7: aa1b828 com.mypackage.app/androidx.work.impl.background.systemjob.SystemJobService
    u0a360 tag=*job*/com.mypackage.app/androidx.work.impl.background.systemjob.SystemJobService
    Source: uid=u0a360 user=0 pkg=com.mypackage.app
    JobInfo:
      Service: com.mypackage.app/androidx.work.impl.background.systemjob.SystemJobService
      Requires: charging=false batteryNotLow=false deviceIdle=false
      Extras: mParcelledData.dataSize=180
      Minimum latency: +29m59s973ms
      Backoff: policy=1 initial=+30s0ms
      Has early constraint
    Required constraints: TIMING_DELAY [0x80000000]
    Satisfied constraints: TIMING_DELAY DEVICE_NOT_DOZING BACKGROUND_NOT_RESTRICTED [0x82400000]
    Unsatisfied constraints: WITHIN_QUOTA [0x1000000]
    Tracking: TIME QUOTA
    Implicit constraints:
      readyNotDozing: true
      readyNotRestrictedInBg: true
    Standby bucket: FREQUENT
    Base heartbeat: 0
      Deferred since: -1h47m30s949ms
    Enqueue time: -1h48m0s986ms
    Run time: earliest=-1h18m1s13ms, latest=none, original latest=none
    Last run heartbeat: 0
    Ready: false (job=false user=true !pending=true !active=true !backingup=true comp=true)
```

This is the problem `Unsatisfied constraints: WITHIN_QUOTA [0x1000000]`, but unfortunately I not able to find a documentation for this kind of errors. The official one from google is quite vague: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/how-to/debugging

This is how I schedule the Work:

```
if (PreferenceController.getInstance().getEmailNotificationInerval() != -1) {
    int interval = PreferenceController.getInstance().getEmailNotificationInerval();

    Constraints constraints = new Constraints.Builder().build();
    PeriodicWorkRequest emailsRequest = new PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(CheckNewEmailWorker.class, interval, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .setConstraints(constraints)
            .build();
    WorkManager.getInstance(context).enqueueUniquePeriodicWork(CheckNewEmailWorker.TAG, ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.KEEP, emailsRequest);
}
```

And I use a `BOOT_COMPLETED` receiver to start it on boot.

In the worker I return `Result.success()` if everything goes OK, and `Result.failure()` if an exception is rised (for example no connection).

Answer (score 0):

You have unsatisfied constraints. This is why your `Worker` is not being executed.

```
Unsatisfied constraints: WITHIN_QUOTA [0x1000000]
```

This usually means that your application is running too many job scheduler jobs. That's why you are running out of `quota`. Also, your `quota` is determined by the [app standby](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/appstandby) bucket you might be ending up in.

We added some documentation to help diagnosing this:
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/how-to/debugging

Comment: Hi, how is possible that I run too many jobs? As you can see in my question, I use unique work, with KEEP policy. And I run this code only on BOOT_COMPLETED and when the main activity's onCreate, I really cannot understand how can I go out of quota..

Comment: What are the solutions to avoid getting WITHIN_QUOTA. I even use foreground service (to avoid hidding background service) and I'm getting this issue. Is there is anything we can do to set a periodic work working?