# Where I can find JobScheduler debug documentation

Tags: android, android-workmanager, android-jobscheduler

I have the following data from the debug:

```
 JOB #u0a231/5: a2826a0 com.abc.workmanagertest/androidx.work.impl.background.systemjob.SystemJobService
    u0a231 tag=*job*/com.abc.workmanagertest/androidx.work.impl.background.systemjob.SystemJobService
    Source: uid=u0a231 user=0 pkg=com.abc.workmanagertest
    JobInfo:
      Service: com.abc.workmanagertest/androidx.work.impl.background.systemjob.SystemJobService
      Flags: 2
      Requires: charging=false batteryNotLow=false deviceIdle=false
      Trigger content URIs:
        1 content://media/internal/video/media
        1 content://media/external/video/media
        1 content://media/internal/images/media
        1 content://media/external/images/media
      Trigger update delay: +1m0s0ms
      Trigger max delay: +10m0s0ms
      Extras: mParcelledData.dataSize=180
      Network type: NetworkRequest [ NONE id=0, [ Capabilities: NOT_METERED&INTERNET&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED&VALIDATED Uid: 10231 AdministratorUids: [] RequestorUid: -1 RequestorPackageName: null] ]
      Backoff: policy=1 initial=+30s0ms
    Required constraints: CONNECTIVITY CONTENT_TRIGGER [0x14000000]
    Dynamic constraints:
    Satisfied constraints: CONNECTIVITY CONTENT_TRIGGER DEVICE_NOT_DOZING BACKGROUND_NOT_RESTRICTED [0x16400000]
    Unsatisfied constraints: WITHIN_QUOTA [0x1000000]
    Tracking: CONNECTIVITY CONTENT QUOTA
    Implicit constraints:
      readyNotDozing: true
      readyNotRestrictedInBg: true
      readyDynamicSatisfied: false
    Network: 103
    Standby bucket: RARE
      Deferred since: -1h4m36s59ms
    Enqueue time: -1h4m36s59ms
    Run time: earliest=none, latest=none, original latest=none
    Restricted due to: none.
    Ready: false (job=false user=true !restricted=true !pending=true !active=true !backingup=true comp=true)
```

As you see the problem for the job not being executed is: **Unsatisfied constraints: WITHIN_QUOTA**

Aren't there any docs with an explanation of what does this means?

I saw the following post, but it is just an opinion:

[Unique periodic work stop executing after a while](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59617213/unique-periodic-work-stop-executing-after-a-while)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify constraints for Job as like [setRequiresCharging](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobInfo.Builder#setRequiresCharging(boolean)). If constraints not met, Job can be stopped with [onStopJob](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobService#onStopJob(android.app.job.JobParameters)). e.g. The job in your dump requires `CONNECTIVITY CONTENT_TRIGGER` constraints.

`Unsatisfied constraints: WITHIN_QUOTA` shows [WITHIN_QUOTA](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/apex/jobscheduler/service/java/com/android/server/job/controllers/JobStatus.java;l=86;drc=master;bpv=1;bpt=1?q=%22Unsatisfied%20constraints:%22) **implicit constraints** unsatisfied for this job - can't run your job without quota. `WITHIN_QUOTA` is implicit constraints (added without explicit constraints setting, see [this code](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/apex/jobscheduler/service/java/com/android/server/job/controllers/JobStatus.java;l=1734;drc=master;bpv=1;bpt=1?q=%22Unsatisfied%20constraints:%22)).

PTAL `QuotaController` [documentation](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/apex/jobscheduler/service/java/com/android/server/job/controllers/QuotaController.java;l=111) for more detail regards [standby bucket](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/appstandby) quota.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! :) Please can you check also this one! :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64878968/why-i-see-unsatisfied-constraints-connectivity-in-jobscheduler-debug-info