# Why I see: Unsatisfied constraints: CONNECTIVITY in JobScheduler debug info

Tags: android, android-workmanager, android-jobscheduler

I set for the job:

```
 val job = JobInfo.Builder(2, ComponentName(context, JobRunner::class.java)).apply {
            setRequiredNetworkType(JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_UNMETERED)
            setRequiresBatteryNotLow(true)
            for (triggerUri in triggers) {
                addTriggerContentUri(JobInfo.TriggerContentUri(triggerUri, JobInfo.TriggerContentUri.FLAG_NOTIFY_FOR_DESCENDANTS))
            }
            setTriggerContentUpdateDelay(TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(1))
            setTriggerContentMaxDelay(TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(10))
        }.build()
        
        jobScheduler.schedule(job)
```

If I execute: **adb shell dumpsys jobscheduler**

I have the following job info:

```
JOB #u0a302/2: 89f4090 com.abc.debug/com.abc.mobile.service.job.JobRunner
    u0a302 tag=*job*/com.abc.debug/com.abc.mobile.service.job.JobRunner
    Source: uid=u0a302 user=0 pkg=com.abc.debug
    JobInfo:
      Service: com.abc.debug/com.abc.mobile.service.job.JobRunner
      Internal flags: 1 HAS_FOREGROUND_EXEMPTION
      Requires: charging=false batteryNotLow=true deviceIdle=false
      Trigger content URIs:
        1 content://media/internal/images/media
        1 content://media/external/images/media
        1 content://media/internal/video/media
        1 content://media/external/video/media
      Trigger update delay: +1m0s0ms
      Trigger max delay: +10m0s0ms
      Network type: NetworkRequest [ NONE id=0, [ Capabilities: NOT_METERED&INTERNET&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED&VALIDATED Unwanted:  Uid: 10302] ]
      Backoff: policy=1 initial=+30s0ms
    Required constraints: BATTERY_NOT_LOW CONNECTIVITY CONTENT_TRIGGER [0x14000002]
    Satisfied constraints: CHARGING BATTERY_NOT_LOW CONTENT_TRIGGER DEVICE_NOT_DOZING BACKGROUND_NOT_RESTRICTED [0x6400003]
    Unsatisfied constraints: CONNECTIVITY [0x10000000]
    Tracking: BATTERY CONNECTIVITY CONTENT
    Standby bucket: RARE
    Base heartbeat: 285
    Enqueue time: -20h50m38s25ms
    Run time: earliest=none, latest=none
    Last run heartbeat: 285
    Ready: false (job=false user=true !pending=true !active=true !backingup=true comp=true)
```

**As seen from the log above I need:**

Network type: NetworkRequest [ NONE id=0, [ Capabilities: NOT_METERED&INTERNET&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED&VALIDATED Unwanted:  Uid: 10302] ]

**I have made another small application on the same device to check the active network capabilities:**

```
 val connMgr = getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
 val networkCap = connMgr.getNetworkCapabilities(connMgr.activeNetwork)
 Log.d("NETWORK_CHECK", "NetworkCapabilities: [$networkCap]")
```

**As seen by the result:**

[ Transports: WIFI Capabilities: NOT_METERED&INTERNET&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED&NOT_VPN&VALIDATED&NOT_ROAMING&FOREGROUND&NOT_CONGESTED&NOT_SUSPENDED LinkUpBandwidth>=1048576Kbps LinkDnBandwidth>=1048576Kbps SignalStrength: -43]

**I have all the capabilities I need. Why I still see the constrain as unsatisfied?**

**Unsatisfied constraints: CONNECTIVITY [0x10000000]**

Is there something else that might be related which is not exactly capability?

I have checked here, but nothing useful have I found: [ConnectivityController](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/apex/jobscheduler/service/java/com/android/server/job/controllers/ConnectivityController.java)

**I have found from another log the following in the Connectivity section:**

```
ConnectivityController:
  Requested standby exceptions: 10336 (1 jobs) 10342 (1 jobs) 10391 (1 jobs)
```

**10391** is my id. What does **Requested standby exceptions** means?

So as per the below suggestion, **I am most likely with restricted Network usage, because I am in the RARE standby bucket.** Check here :

https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/power/power-details

The problem for me is that in the job info above: ~21h hours have passed from the last trigger, and often on some phones **I see even 2 days**. But the docs are saying:

**Deferred up to 24 hours**

So I would like to find more info on what exactly is happening so I could improve.  Not much we have found.

**But the disabling of battery optimization makes a huge difference.  Also when the device is charging we have no problem.**

https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby#support_for_other_use_cases

Comment: One of the `Required constraints` is `CONNECTIVITY` and it is not part of the `Satisfied constraints`. Are you sure it's linked to the `Network Capabilities`? It seems to be two different things

Comment: Can you please share how your JobScheduler is set up?

Comment: @Eselfar if I need Wi-Fi and there is not Wi-Fi I will still have CONNECTIVITY, and the reason will be lack of desired Network Capabilities. But it looks like from the ConnectivityController implementation, that a lot of things are related to the end result. Not only Network Capabilities. I have added the code for job scheduling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is important to note that your application is in the `RARE standy bucket`:

```
 Standby bucket: RARE
```

This means that, even if the device has connectivity, your jobs are going to have access to the network only once a day.

This is documented in the [Power Manager restriction](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/power/power-details) guide with the note:

> If network access is restricted, the app is granted a window of 10 minutes to use the network at the specified interval.

This is probably an application that spends a lot of time in the background with little or no interaction from the user. A possible solution is to increase foreground time adding some functionality that drives the user to open the app.

Comment: Thanks. I am accepting your answer as solved, but to be honest it is not exactly solving my problem. Because as per the documentation  I am expecting to fire at least once per 24 hours for 10 minutes. Because is saying: "Deferred up to 24 hours." But I see much more time. So I am trying to find a concrete reason why. Something more concrete than CONNECTIVITY. At the moment I am reading the commit messages for the ConnectivityController code if I find something useful. And no obvious hack will help me to force the in the higher bucket, as the intention of the app is not to bother the users.

Comment: Another thing that can impact your background Job are OEMs restrictions (as described in https://dontkillmyapp.com/). On which device/OS version are you seeing this behavior?

Comment: Yes. I know the site. For example, XiaoMi is just dead. Jobs are lost. I accept that. Only WM with Battery optimization off is working. JS does not work at all. But at least I am trying to make it reasonably reliable on the mainstream devices like Samsung and Pixel, on which I have seen the issue.  And the specs expectation for the RARE bucket works for me. But when I go for like 2 days with this "bug" the reality makes me feel hopeless :D I know that this is Android so there is no "sure thing", but I am fixing whatever I can. For example on XiaMi - I know why! Here it is blurry for me.